# Algorithm for transforming polygon with points inside

Tags: algorithm, polygon

Sorry, if this is a duplicate. I was trying to find this in Google and Stackoverflow but I couldn't find it. Maybe I can't name correctly what I am looking for.

Let's say that I have a square and inside there are points. Than I change it's points to make quadrangle. How I can now get new coordinates of points after transform? 
[image]

Comment: I am only changing corners of quadrangle, but this will make points (inside quadrangle) be in relative position. I want to get their coordinates

Comment: Interpolation, interpolation, interpolation.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the point that is Y distance from the top and X distance from the left side? For a relative position, you have to tell us what the point's position is relative to. The top-left corner?

Comment: @JimMischel: not really necessary. The point can be thought of being vertically relative to both top and bottom, and the same to left and right. In the sketch, I believe the distance between the left corner and the point should get ever so slightly larger.

Comment: @Jongware: Granted, but the relationship needs to be specified, whatever it is. The question doesn't say anything about relative positions; that's just an assumption on our part. Before I could supply an answer, I'd want to know that it's what he really wants.

Comment: yeah thanks for help :-) I now know that if I want to resize it, i must have origin. it will be placed in center of square

Answer (score 1):

There exist a canonical method for a unit square (a square with one corner at origo and sides of length 1) because coordinates of a point `(x,y)` can be used directly for interpolating within a skewed quadrangle with points at `q00` (which corresponds to origo (x=0, y=0)), `q01` for (x=0, y=1), `q10` for (x=1, y=0) and `q11` for (x=1, y=1). The transformed point is the [bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation):

```
p = (1-x)*(1-y)*q00 + x*(1-y)*q10 + (1-x)*y*q01 + x*y*q11
```

A generalisation of this is to compute `p` as a weighted mean of the polygon corners (the weights must sum to 1). The weights for the quadrangle based on the unit square is:

```
w = { (1-x)*(1-y); x*(1-y); (1-x)*y; x*y }
q = { q00; q10; q01; q11 }
p = w * q
```

Where `w * q` is a dot product. Weights for a triangle are computed by solving `p0 = w * q0` for `sum(w)=1`, where `p0` is the original point and `q0` are the original corner points.

The general case with a polygon has multiple solutions. One way that works quite ok (in a simple test I did) is to form triangles from all triplets of corners in the polygon that covers a given point, compute the weights of the triangles, and use their combined weight over all corners as `w` in `p = w * q`.

Comment: can you give me an example code if there is a "relative point" for example in center of square?

Comment: I clarified the answer to explain bilinear interpolation, and added a description of a general case for arbitrary polygons.